# Symfony Guard Authenticator customize logout function

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-guard

I'm new to Symfony and I'm learning how to use Guard to authenticate users. Currently using Symfony 3.2. I followed [Creating your first Symfony app and adding authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-symfony-app-and-adding-authentication/) tutorial which helped me alot but in my aplication I have to add some custom data into session and I have no idea how remove it from session after redirect into logoutAction() function. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The `invalidate_session` variable (part of the `logout` block of your firewall, defaults to `true`) automatically invalidates a session on logout, so unless you changed that you should be fine already?

Comment: Yes, thank you sir. Do you maybe know onAuthenticationSuccess() function is fine for add my custom data into session after success authentication?